# Solving Shifted Data IVP with Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I am currently trying to solve this IVP using Laplace transforms:

\begin{cases} y''+y=2t\\ y(\pi/4) = \pi/2\\ y'(\pi/4) = 2-\sqrt(2) \end{cases}

However, I am not exactly sure of what to do since the initial conditions are not given at "0" and so I am not able to use the Laplace Transform derivative property, in the textbook I am studying from I think it was solved using some sort of substitution, however I do not understand why this works or how it works.

So how should I approach such problem using a substitution?

Comment: Make the substitution $w = t - \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Id have to use the chain rule to get " y'' " correct ? and how would this substitution not change the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, using Laplace transform it is not hard to see that:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{y}''\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\text{s}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)\tag1$$

And:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[2x\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{2}{\text{s}^2}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)=\frac{2}{\text{s}^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{2}{\text{s}^4}+\frac{\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}+\frac{\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)}{\text{s}^2}\tag3$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, we can see that:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{x^3}{3}+\text{y}\left(0\right)+\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)\cdot x\tag4$$

using your initial conditions, we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{y}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^3+\text{y}\left(0\right)+\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\\
\text{y}'\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2+\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)=2-\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

So, this gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{y}\left(0\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^3-\left(2-\sqrt{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2\right)\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi\left(24\sqrt{2}+\pi^2\right)}{96}\\
\\
\text{y}'
 \left(0\right)=2-\sqrt{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

So, the solution is:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{\pi\left(24\sqrt{2}+\pi^2\right)}{96}+\left(2-\sqrt{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2\right)x\tag7$$

Comment: Thanks this makes sense to me, but do you have any idea on how I would solve it using a substitution instead ?

Comment: I also think you missed to add the transform of y(x) which would be Y(s) in (1) but I got the idea nevertheless.